# How to count using a conditional in Django?

Tags: python, django

Let's say we have the following simplistic models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264)

   def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"

class Status(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264)

   def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "status"

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Status choices would be: Sold, Not Sold, Reserved, Withdrawn.

My aim is for each category to get the total amount of products and how many were Sold or Reserved as a percentage of the total per category:

```
qs = Product.objects.all().values("category__name").annotate(total_products=Count("id"), total_available=Cast((Count(Case(When(status__name__in=["Sold", "Reserved"], then=True), output_field=BooleanField())) / Count("id")) * 100., FloatField()))
```

For some categories returns the correct result and for others it does not.

Comment: Is the `Product` the same with the model `Bet`?

Comment: @RieljunLiguid Yeah, it was corrected.

Comment: I have added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate first the sold_count and reserved_count together with the total_count and then annotate again with it.  Something like below should work:

```
from django.db import models


status_list = [
    'Sold',
    'Reserved',
]
# Build Case query
count_query = {}
percent_query = {}
for status in status_list:
    count_key = '{}_count'.format(status.lower())
    count_query[count_key] = models.Sum(
        models.Case(
            models.When(
                status__name=status,
                then=models.Value(1.0)
            ),
            default=0.0,
            output_field=models.FloatField()
        ))

    percent_key = '{}_percent'.format(status.lower())
    percent_query[percent_key] = models.ExpressionWrapper(
        models.F(count_key) / models.F('total_products') * 100.0,
        output_field=models.FloatField()
    )


queryset = Product.objects.values('category__name').annotate(
    total_products=models.Count('id'),
    **count_query
)
queryset = queryset.annotate(**percent_query)
```

**For Django >= 2.0**

There is a better implementation using [Conditional Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation)